# ¿Cómo puedo hacerle para mantener 2 o más ventanas del compilador de c/c++ y que ambas estén ejecutándose a la vez?

Tags: c#, c++

Por ejemplo, tengo un compilador ejecutándose en otro archivo .cpp aparte y solamente puedo ejecutar uno a la vez. Donde más me pasa es en este caso:
[image: En esta imagen yo quiero por ejemplo utilizar la ventana del compilador más grande mientras la ventana pequeña(en este caso del cronometro) se esta ejecutando al mismo tiempo, como puedo hacer eso?]

Comment: ¿ No se te ha ocurrido abrir una consola y ejecutar tu programa desde la línea de comandos ? Puedes abrir **todas** las consolas que quieras :-)

Comment: Abre la consola y ve a la ruta de tu proyecto `cd C:\Users\DELL\Desktop`, luego solo ejecuta tu programa `"Programa 3.exe"`. Abres otra consola y repites el proceso.